# Entity Framework (many to many)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
    public partial class ALBUMS
    {
        public ALBUMS()
        {
            this.PHOTOS = new HashSet<PHOTOS>();
        }

        public int ID_ALBUM { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PHOTOS> PHOTOS { get; set; }
    }

public partial class PHOTOS
    {
        public PHOTOS()
        {
            this.ALBUMS = new HashSet<ALBUMS>();
        }

        public int ID_PHOTO { get; set; }
        public string PATH { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ALBUMS> ALBUMS { get; set; }
    }
```

Вставляю новую фотографию так но хотелось бы сразу её добавлять в альбом, как это сделать?

```
            PHOTOS photo = new PHOTOS();
            photo.PATH = filename;
            ALBUMS album = GetAlbum(idAlbum);
            album.PHOTOS.Add(photo);
            photo.ALBUMS.Add(album);
            GaleryEntities.PHOTOS.Add(photo);
            GaleryEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Не удалось обновить набор `EntitySet "PHOTO-ALBUM"`, поскольку в нем имеется запрос `DefiningQuery` и отсутствует элемент `<InsertFunction>` в элементе `<ModificationFunctionMapping>` для поддержки текущей операции.

Comment: одно фото может принадлежать сразу нескольким альбомам?

Comment: Так точно!

Comment: Попробуй здесь GaleryEntities.PHOTOS.Add(new PHOTOS { PATH = filename}); передавать еще коллекцию альбомов. А в сеттере свойства public virtual ICollection<ALBUMS> ALBUMS { get; set; } обрабатывать новое значение(коллекцию) value, и добавлять в эти альбомы новое фото.

Comment: Делаю так
                    PHOTOS photo = new PHOTOS();
                    photo.PATH = filename;
                    ALBUMS album = GetAlbum(idAlbum);
                    album.PHOTOS.Add(photo);
                    photo.ALBUMS.Add(album);
                    GaleryEntities.PHOTOS.Add(photo);
                    GaleryEntities.SaveChanges();

Ошибка Не удалось обновить набор EntitySet "PHOTO-ALBUM", поскольку в нем имеется запрос DefiningQuery и отсутствует элемент <InsertFunction> в элементе <ModificationFunctionMapping> для поддержки текущей операции.

Comment: попробуй задать первичные ключи в сущностях. Это можно сделать с помощью атрибута [Key]. А вот наткнулся на пример, похожий на твой http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482670/entity-framework-code-first-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype

Comment: Да, всё получислось когда задал первичные ключ в таблице "связке"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таблице связке должен был быть составной первичный ключ из id_photo и id_album.